# Prevent users from disabling Google ads in android application

Tags: android, in-app, admob

I was wondering if it was possible to prevent users with root access to disable in-app adverts in an android app. Lucky patcher with root has the ability to remove ads so was wondering if it could be done or it's a google flaw?

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if it was possible to prevent users with root access to disable in-app adverts in an android app.

No. If you have root you have full control of the device and can use tools such as Lucky Patcher to basically change the source and remove the ads; dependencies and references.

> Lucky patcher with root has the ability to remove ads so was wondering if it could be done or it's a google flaw?

Yes, Lucky Patcher can remove ads. It changes the source code and gives the user the new apk, ad-free, license free and whatever else the user has done.

---

An APK can be defined as a form of a zipped file; It contains the source and can be decoded and changed. You **cannot prevent the user from changing the source code when you basically hand it over in the form of an APK**. Non-root users can decompile the app and change the source if they want to, and remove ads.

Comment: Thank you. So basically users can exploit it.

Comment: Root or no root, the source can be decompiled and changed. Lucky Patcher allows the user to use an app and change it in minutes instead of having to edit the source code manually. The last is something only competent users(users who know code) can do, and takes a long time. Ads can also be blocked by turning off internet connections before opening the app, so the ads don't load. There are many ways to block ads, and Lucky Patcher removes the code that shows ads. It can be removed manually as well, but it takes a longer time