# How to detect if app is installed on a Physical Device Vs Virtual Device / Emulator?

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion, bluestacks

I am developing an app for which its really important that it does not give access to app functions if app is installed on a Virtual Device e.g Genymotion, Bluestacks and other similar emulators

I have tried using few identifiers such as Device ID,  Sensors,  Fingerprint etc. But all of these fail with these emulators when clubbed with Bluestacks tweaker eg. BS Tweak etc that assigns Physical Device level values to these identifiers even on the emulator.

So, any help on getting this issue sorted out will be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can find that your application running in Real device or Virtual device or Emulator. And for this you have to use `fingerPrint`.  By the `Model` you also can get the actual virtual device name. Here is the sample code and you can detect it is an emulator or not.

N.B: `fingerPrint` not only return `UNKNOWN` for the virtual device it also returns `GENERIC`

```
public static boolean isEmulator() {
        return Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
                || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
                || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
                || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
                || (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic"))
                || "google_sdk".equals(Build.PRODUCT);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the other answers: Please note, that a user might be able to unpack the application and remove this kind of protection. Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981996/prevent-users-from-disabling-google-ads-in-android-application/43982057) for reference.